# Why doesn't rsync work when connecting to NCBI's FTP server home page?

Tags: ftp, rsync, bioinformatics, ncbi

I'm currently trying to update some code at work.  I previously created a script with an up to date version of Python that logs a users path choices on NCBI's FTP webiste (ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/).  The log was used to update my file system with updated files (NCBI updates their files weekly I believe).  I basically recreated the wheel.  I want to use rsync now, but I can't seem to get what I want...

```
rsync -vah --include "\*/" --exclude "\*" rsync://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/
```

The above script should go to NCBI's website and begin downloading directories.  Instead it prints to the shell a list of folders in the NCBI home directory and then terminates without copying anything.

**Here is what the output looks like:**

```
**Warning Notice!**

**You are accessing a U.S. Government information system which includes this
computer, network, and all attached devices. This system is for
Government-authorized use only. Unauthorized use of this system may result in
disciplinary action and civil and criminal penalties. System users have no
expectation of privacy regarding any communications or data processed by this
system. At any time, the government may monitor, record, or seize any
communication or data transiting or stored on this information system.**

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Welcome to the NCBI rsync server.**

 - 1000genomes
 - bigwig
 - bioproject
 - biosample
 - blast
 - cgap
 - cn3d
 - dbgap
 - entrez
 - epigenomics
 - fa2htgs
 - genbank
 - gene
 - genomes
 - hapmap
 - mmdb
 - ncbi-asn1
 - pathogen
 - pubchem
 - pubmed
 - pub
 - refseq
 - repository
 - SampleData
 - sequin
 - sky-cgh
 - snp
 - sra
 - tech-reports
 - toolbox
 - tpa
 - tracedb
 - variation 

[user@host ~/bin $]
```

Whenever I use

```
rsync://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/destination
```

(basically if I include any directory inside of NCBI's FTP homepage) everything seems to work fine.

What should I do here?  What is the problem/solution?